# Packaging scala code into a jar file with proguard not working

Tags: scala, proguard, xsbt-proguard-plugin

I have a directory structure of this:

```
CSV_generator
  src
   main
    scala
     CSVGenerator.scala
  project
   plugins.sbt
```

The contents of my scala object is this:

```
package tools.csv_generator

object CSV_Generator{
 import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
 import java.io.File
 import org.rogach.scallop._

def main(args: Array[String]){
  val opts = new ScallopConf(args) {

  banner("""This is the program CSV Generator""")
  val file_path = opt[String]("file_path",
                              required = true,
                              descr = "File Path")
  val dome_string = opt[String]("dome_string",
                                required = true,
                                descr = "Dome String")
  }
```

My csv_generator/project/plugins.sbt:

```
  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-proguard" % "0.2.2")
```

My csv_generator/build.sbt is:

```
  proguardSettings

  ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq("-dontnote", "-dontwarn", "-ignorewarnings"
                                     , "-keepclasseswithmembers  class                    scala.CSV_Generator")

  ProguardKeys.options in Proguard +=         ProguardOptions.keepMain("src.main.scala.CSV_Generator")
```

In my sbt when I run `proguard:proguard` trying to package all my code in a runnable standalone jar file, I get this:

```
  [error] Error: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
  [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last proguard:proguard for the full output.
  [error] (proguard:proguard) Proguard failed with exit code [1]
  [error] Total time: 14 s, completed Jan 31, 2014 12:18:38 AM
```

There are very little examples for proguard for a small app like mine. Can someone help ?

Comment: Your directory structure is not really visible in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to keep the main method as an entry point:

```
-keep class scala.CSV_Generator {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

ProGuard normally warns about this; better not switch off warnings and notes.

See the ProGuard documentation > Examples > [A typical application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#application)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I added this, but now the problem seems to be that proguard seems to run forever, the process does not seem to end.

Answer (score 0):

One less powerful solution that works closer to clojure's uberjar that I found suited me just great is the sbt "one-jar". Can be found here:

https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar

Works with a few lines of config and everything is packaged up fine. This is closer to what I need.